# How run avr-gcc Arduino on Android

Tags: android, compiler-construction, android-ndk, arduino, avr-gcc

Is possible to use AVR-GCC compiler which includes Arduino1.0.5 in Android?

I'm trying to run AVR-GCC included in the Arduino 1.0.5 on Android but this don't work! I use the Arduino 1.0.5 for Linux, hoped that this compiler will work on Android because is a distrubution of Linux.

I install andavr [andavr](https://code.google.com/p/andavr/) but this has a big size about 280 MB in Android device and the AVR-GCC of Arduino 1.0.5 is the about 30 MB, so, how can I run the Arduino 1.0.5 compiler on  Android?

Comment: You could try [ArduinoDroid](http://arduinodroid.blogspot.com/)

Comment: yes this is a other option but their SDK doesn't compile the WiFi library.

Answer (score 0):

You can cross-compile the avr toolchain for android with the arm toolchain (codesourcery?)
I've never tried that, but I really want to.
Also, there is a way to program arduino via bt (with hc-05 module, google it), so if you cross-compile avrdude for android, you can fully program an arduino from your android.
I'll definetly do that... :)